# unable to run the code for Rtsp Play from Github

Tags: iphone, xcode4.4, rtsp-client, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to run the rtsp protocol in iphone so i have downloaded the code for RtspPlay from this link :

[RTSPPLAY Github](https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RTSPPlay)
I am using latest Xcode 4.4.1.
But I am facing problem to run this code in my device because of error.

> Error is: Entitlements.plist could not be find.

Please download this code from given link and let me know what can i do.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have run this code by adding Entitlements.plist from NewFile in project. I have no getting any error BUT not able to run in device. This shows a Pop Up "TIMED OUT WAITING FOR APP TO LAUNCH".
Tell me what can i do in this case?

Comment: Hi Guys, i have successfully run this code
Cheers

Comment: could you please show me the source code?
I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

others have run this code without issue, we've tested with Xcode 4.3 , entitlement file reference can just be deleted in the build settings, I think no entitlement is better than trying to use one from a different app.

We will investigate further, and update our repository if needed, we want rtspplay to be a serious contender in mobile video , thank you for your feedback

Comment: Hi Michelle, Thanks for your answer. I have run the code BUT i am unable to play it Media player in iphone. How can i do this. Please suggest.

Comment: I am shocking there is no answer for this post. It means there is no anyone who knows RTSP play in iphone. In the other hand there are various apps available in itunes store like http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/oplayer-lite-best-free-video/id385907472?mt=8